# Saving edited vectors to new file does not save changes?

Tags: qgis

Perhaps I do not understand how QGIS saves edits but here is what I am experiencing.

1. Load up a vector .shp file
2. Immediately "SAVE AS" and give it a different name.
3. Delete some vector lines on the new file.
4. Save the edits.
5. Drop the edited .shp file into Global Mapper.  All the deleted vector lines are still there!

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding on how QGIS saves edits?

Comment: Yes, issue 11007 is exactly what I am seeing.  You say if I save it to disk the deletes will be reflected.   Isn't that what 'Save As' is in QGIS.  It is writing a new file to my disk.  Actually 6 of them.  When I make an edit and save as only 3 of the six files are updated.

Answer (score 1):

Save Edits just commits that transaction to the datastore. If you then save it to disk the deletes will be reflected.

Comment: It may also be due to a known issue https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11007. It is possible to delete features without removing them physically from the .shp and .shx parts of shapefile by marking them deleted in the .dbf file. However, all software do not check the deleted flag from .dbf.

Comment: Not in this case I think.